# Azure Function: - System.Text.Json: The input does not contain any JSON tokens

Tags: azure, function, system.text.json

I use Rider to create a new Azure Function by template, TimerTrigger based, almost everything by default, but got "System.Text.Json: The input does not contain any JSON tokens." The code is

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.FunctionApp2;

public static class timeFunc
{
    [FunctionName("timeFunc")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    
    }
}
```

And the error is

```
[2023-10-16T01:38:50.051Z] The listener for function 'timeFunc' was unable to start.
[2023-10-16T01:38:50.054Z] The listener for function 'timeFunc' was unable to start.System.Text.Json: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

local.settings.json is

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

it's weird that this function doesn't even use "System.Text.Json". Can anyone offer some help, thanks a lot

Btw, I created another HTTPTrigger function, which works

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution in rider by using azure function template like below:

[image]

After created a solution added a timer trigger function like below:

[image]

azure-functions-core-tools package got installed successfully.

If you don't mention the version in `host.json` it will take latest version. In case the version is mentioned rebuild the project again and execute the Function mentioned.

The timer trigger function is executed successfully in my local environment.
check the below:

[image]

**function:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.FunctionApp1;

public static class timeFunc
{
    [FunctionName("timeFunc")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{  
  "version": "2.0",  
  "logging": {  
  "applicationInsights": {  
  "samplingSettings": {  
  "isEnabled": true,  
  "excludedTypes": "Request"  
  },  
  "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true  
  }  
 }
 }
```